# Synch RaspberryPi directory with OneDrive via rclone

Tags: raspberry-pi, onedrive, symlink, rclone

I have an issue and don't know who to ask to solve it. Hopefully you can help me out.
My Raspberry Pi (no desktop environment)has access (write and read) to my `Microsoft OneDrive directories` via `rclone` already. Now my idea was to synch a directory which is currently safed on my raspberry automatically to my OneDrive account.

I thought this is possible with a symbolic link, like this:
`ln -s /my/raspberry/dir /my/onedrive/dir`:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/my/onedrive/dir': Input/output error
```

Is there a better way to do this? I think OneDrive does not support symbolic links :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. You can use `rclone` and sync the directories with `rclone sync /source/path/ /destination/path/`. If needed you can write a shellscript which runs in background to sync both directories in an endless loop.